# "Der Salat wird gemacht" oder "ist gemacht"

Tags: passive

I want to translate the following sentence: The healthiest salad is made without any oil.
Would that correspond to :

1. "Der gesündeste Salat ist ohne Öl gemacht" or
2. "Der gesündeste Salat wird ohne Öl gemacht"

I'm leaning towards option 1 because it's a finished action, not an ongoing process. However, the DeepL translator translated it as option 2, which confused me.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Automatic translation might not always be correct. I would understand 1 as referring to a specific salad, e.g. the healthiest of some salads that have been prepared, while I understand 2 as more general, refering to salad as a category or as a rule for making salad. It is a finished action only if there is actually a prepared salad, not if you are referring to salad as a category or salad in general.

Answer (score 3):

Although both variants are grammatical, they do not mean the same thing. For making an informed choice, the context would be needed. Out of context, I couldn't figure out why variant 1 should be used. This variant with "ist" is not a passive; as Janka said, it's like a construction with an adjective. This sentence would often be understood as speaking about a particular salad that has been made, and what it is like. Perhaps it could also refer to a type of salad, as a generalising statement, but it's not clear. Maybe that's why this felt pretty odd for me at first.

I would prefer the second variant because its meaning is more neutral. However, it would be much clearer and simpler to say "Der gesündeste Salat ist einer, der kein Öl enthält" (in contrast to the "ist gemacht" construction, this would never presuppose an existing salad, it's clearly about a type of salad).

Comment: I think the effect I get is because you could easily form a clause without "gemacht": in the spoken language you also get "Der Salat ist ohne Öl" (but "enthält kein Öl" is better style). So by way of contrast, the addition of "gemacht" invites the idea that a particular salad "has been made", and you don't want this emphasis. (This is just a guess to explain my intuition)

Answer (score 0):

Both are okay. There's no hard rule about that. If you want to emphasize on the result, use *sein*. If you want to emphasize on the action, use *werden*.

In practice, use *sein* if you want to use the Partizip II like an adjective.

> Der Salat ist frisch.

> Der Salat ist gekühlt.

There's no agency in those sentences. There's only the salad and its properties. Compare

> Der Salat wird gekühlt.

In this case we have to think about the fridge which drives the process. It's about an action that the fridge does, told from the perspective of the salad.

The reason why DeepL proposes *werden* in your example is because it's far more common in that context. And the reason for that is that we should think about what we do when we make salad as we are reading that. This isn't about the salad but about us. It's about what we do, told from the perspective of the salad.